# 4 weeks “with editor” normal?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

I have submitted a math paper to an Elsevier journal. Before submitting it, I sent two separate polite emails to two editors (experts of the field) of the journal and asked them if they think my paper fits the standards of the journal, they both replied that the paper is very interesting and please submit to [..]. Moreover, I gave a few talks about my work and asked the people who invited me if they will consider reviewing my paper when later it gets submitted, they said yes. So when I submitted, I suggested appropriate editors and reviewers. However after around 4 weeks, the status of my paper is still “with editor”, I hoped since I suggested 4 reviewers and 2 editors my paper gets to review stage faster. Is it ok if I send an email to editor about the status? Can this hurt in anyway? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It really does seem to me like you're over-reading this. Take a breath, forget about the paper for at least 3 months.

Comment: The short answers are: it's not normal, you can send a reminder, and it is unlikely to hurt.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new normal. Just like reviewers, editors grow tired of unpaid and underappreciated work. With growing demands from teaching and research side of academic life, there is less time to dedicate to *service*. This is particularly true for early career academics,  who often spend unhealthy hours writing papers and teaching classes to boost their track record and establish themselves in academia.